# Get Display CHOICE in a ForeignKey Django Model

Tags: django

My models:

```
class Sell(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Buy, related_name='sell', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    code = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    status_choice = (
        ("W", "Aguardando aprovação do pagamento"),
        ("A", "Pagamento aprovado - produto em separação"),
    )

    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_choice, default='W')
```

My views:

```
def order(request):
    orders = Sell.objects.values('code__code', 'date', 'code__status') \
        .annotate(total_paid=Sum('total_paid')). \
        filter(buyer__username=request.user.username).order_by('-date')

    return render(request, 'orders/orders.html',
                  {'orders': orders})
```

My template:

```
{% for order in orders %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ order.code__code }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.date }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.get_code__status_display }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The output I was expecting: "Aguardando aprovação do pagamento" but it's not printing this.

Any help to display the full text instead the only word "W"?

Thank you!

Comment: `orders` is an iterable of `Sell` objects? That's confusing...

Comment: Sorry, I missed the views! Just updated...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a period/full-stop/`.` to access objects related by a `ForeignKey`

```
{% for order in orders %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ order.code.code }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.date }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.code.get_status_display }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work. If I chang the first line like you said `{{ sell.code.code }}`, nothing is printed! I also updated the code attaching the views.py

Comment: Did you rename the context? I changed the naming to match your context/template

Comment: Yes, but with no success - nothing is printed. Here is the output of `{{ order }}`: `{'code__code': '2DB0ED9B-2756-4F86-BCB0-82A13E5E7C25', 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 29), 'code__status': 'W', 'total_paid': Decimal('60.00')}`